# How to get top 3 records on the same output row in a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone help me with this SQL query?
Assuming the following tables:

```
student: student_id, first_name, last_name, age
classes: class_id, class_name
student_classes: class_id, student_id     # junction table
```

I'm trying to build a query to select each class and show the top 3 oldest students assigned to each class. With the following output:

```
class_id, class_name, top1_first_name, top1_age, top2_first_name, top2_age, top3_first_name, top3_age
```

I'm stuck on how to present the output like this on the same output row

Comment: Consider adding debugging details, including sample input tables, expected output, your query attempt (if any) and why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Isn't it easier to download the query to HTML/JavaScript and use all the formatting tools there?